# Is there a substitute available for multi pane development beside fragment in android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I went to an interview today and the interviewer asked me, "What would you use instead of fragments for multipane development?". I was blank at that time. If anyone knows the answer please tell me.

Comment: You can create multipane layout by creating custom View classes instead of Fragments.

Comment: Thanx I'll try that